# XCode: String URL to Image

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, image, url

How can I convert image from URL (String) to Image in XCode (Objective-C)?
I have an images in URL. And I want to make the Array with this images but how images. Than I can read they in my IPhone aplicatioon. Thanks for help!

Comment: whats the url for image?

Answer (score 13):

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL : url];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData: data];
```

Just remember that [-dataWithContentsOfURL:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSData/initWithContentsOfURL%3a) is a synchronous call and should not be performed on the main thread.

Comment: +1 for pointing out sync.

Comment: Also note that `-dataWithContentsOfURL:` ignores any cookies whatsoever, so if you are attempting to access a file that is protected by login, you'll need to use the much more complex `NSURLConnection` class.

Answer (score 5):

**This is how to do it,**

```
NSString *imageUrlString = @"";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:imageUrlString];
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imgURL]]];
```

Comment: Please explain your answer in words as well.

Comment: It creates img from the data obtained from the URL.

Comment: The hell with words... This dude is AWESOME! I just used exactly that line and it was EXACTLY what I was looking for.  Still working in iOS 8.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use some kind of Image loader like [this one](https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView).

It will load the image in background and set it to an ImageView when it's ready. It gives a way better experience as user.